# Sliding Drawer with multiple handles

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

I want to create sliding drawers which comes from right to left which has two handles for loading different contents. Handles position should be in between center and bottom of the screen, so that whenever I slide with any handle, application should show the corresponding content on the whole screen.

I checked earlier sliding drawer's questions and solutions, but could not help to my scenario.

- By default slide drawer's handle position is centre right to the
  screen. And when I place two handles, second handle is over-lapping
  the other, and I can see only one handle.
- Tried keeping PaddingBottom as 200dp. Now I could see both the
  handles, but second slide drawer's content is shown for both the
  handles.
- Kept slide drawers inside linear layout, and assigned layout_weight
  as 1 for both slide drawers. With this, complete screen is divided
  into two equal parts. But I want to use whole screen for each handle.

Could someone help in this regard.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The sliding drawer can be placed in a frame or relative layout according to the developer's site. And you can set the top offset for your layout inside the layout present in the drawer which is in the xml. Hope it works. Worked fine for my code.

Comment: @stusthi-can you please give your sample code?i need it please